# Is it possible to have an SEO friendly Express.js Web site?

Tags: javascript, node.js, seo, webserver, express

If Express provides a traditional route structure (i.e. http://yoursite.com/foo), will the pages show up on Google's Search Engine Results Page, similar to say a Wordpress blog or PHP Web site using the same path structure?

Comment: I don't think this question is "not constructive"

Comment: Why do yo not think it constructive? Please explain, so I might modify before it gets closed.

Comment: I've heard that many rumors get started this way.  :-)  What's the source of your concern?

Comment: Sorry - meant to say I didn't think it was not constructive - typo on my part

Comment: I have revised to avoid starting a debate. I have simplified the question.

Comment: If ExpressJS requires client-side JavaScript to render content, then it would be considered NOT SEO friendly. I did a quick test on a couple ExpressJS [example sites](http://expressjs.com/applications.html) with JavaScript turned off and the sites still render correctly - so I would consider them SEO friendly.

Comment: That's great. I suppose there might be some work to do in the response headers as @rekire mentions below, but I believe this means the answer to my question is "yes".

Comment: Sure, express is server side rendering. the problem is when you generate your html client side, where google won't be able to index it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your ressource? IMHO your information is wrong. The Url can be uses for some merge logical data.

This has nothing to do with caching, that has much to do with the response headers of your webserver:

- Etag: a tag for identifying if the content has changed
- Last-Modified: a way to check if the content has changed in the meantime
- Expires: the time how long the page should be cached without recontacting the server again.

For more details see also [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_header) or the [RFC2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt).

Comment: Does that mean Google would crawl the particular pages and list them on their SERP?

Comment: What is SERP? Please explain that

Comment: Search Engine Results Page.

Comment: It is possible that the search engines will use this informations, but I would recomment to do this with microdata. There you can be sure that the search enging will read the data in the correct way. This could be helpful for you: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=1088474&answer=185417